# Android POST Request returning 403 from AWS API Gateway

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS Lambda w/ API gateway triggers and I am running into an issue.

I'm using RetroFit to make a POST request and I'm getting a 403 for my response back. I am passing a JSON with a URL where the amazon service will do something with it. Is there something I need to put in the headers? I removed authorization from the request.

Here is the raw message and it doesn't give me a detailed message.

"Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/lio}"

Interface/Retrofit service

```
public interface AmazonService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8")
    @POST("/lio")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getAmazonResponse(@Body JSONObject input);
}
```

---

```
amazonRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .callbackExecutor(executor)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/")
            .build();


AmazonService as = amazonRetrofit.create(AmazonService.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("url", "www.google.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Observable<ResponseBody> obs = as.getAmazonResponse(jsonObject);

    obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response onCompleted()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response onError()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ResponseBody response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "response onNext()");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you also post how you use RetroFit to make the request and your API configuration?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Did you enable any auth on your method, like AWS Auth, Cognito User Pool, Custom Auth?

Comment: Auth: NONE on my POST request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using Retrofit 2, and Retrofit 2 uses the same rules as .

If you have a leading '/' on your path, it will consider as absolute path.

```
public interface AmazonService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8")
    @POST("/lio")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getAmazonResponse();
}

amazonRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl("https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/")
        .build();
```

Result: https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/lio

If you remove the leading '/' on your path, it will consider as related path.

```
public interface AmazonService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8")
    @POST("lio")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getAmazonResponse();
}

amazonRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl("https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/")
        .build();
```

Result: https://eun533ayha.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/lio

In your case, it looks like that you have a stage 'Prod' and your integration is on the resource '/lio'. I think it will work if you remove the leading '/'.

Comment: It worked! Now the JSON I am passing into the Body isn't being recognized on the Lambda function. I modified the code above to pass the JSON.

Comment: Any suggestions on the json?

Comment: You can create your own model to match your body schema.
```public interface AmazonService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8")
    @POST("lio")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getAmazonResponse(@Body ApiRequest body);
}```

Comment: Instead of passing a JSON I passed in a HashMap<String, String> and it worked.