# How to avoid null response in MVVM pattern?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern in my android project. Every time I do registration it doesn't satisfies the following response `if (response != null && response.isSuccessful())`

### Activity

```
private void observeRegistration() {
        final Register payLoad = new Register();
        payLoad.setMsisdn(binding.registerMsisdn.getText().toString().trim());
    payLoad.setToken(TOKEN);
        payLoad.setApiKey(API_KEY);
        payLoad.setDeviceOs("ANDROID");
        Log.i("Instance", String.valueOf(AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().getAccessToken()));
        registerViewModel.register(payLoad).observe(this, new Observer<Response<RegisterResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Response<RegisterResponse> response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().setSignedUp(true);
                    AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().setMSISDN(binding.registerMsisdn.getText().toString().trim());
                    Utility.launchActivity(RegistrationActivity.this, DiallerActivity.class, null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Register failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(response));
                }
            }
        });
```

### RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<Response<RegisterResponse>> liveData;
    public RegisterViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
    public LiveData<Response<RegisterResponse>> register(Register payload) {
        liveData = RegisterRepository.getInstance().register(payload);
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

The Log I am getting is `Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=aws_url}`. What is the mistake in my coding?

Comment: code==403 -> `response.isSuccessful()` is false

Comment: Probably in what thing I'm doing the mistake? or just remove the condition to make it work?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Kindly check regarding absolute path and relative path, This issues come up with aws server. Do modification with your end point url by "/". For more details kindly refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702899/android-post-request-returning-403-from-aws-api-gateway

Comment: Thank you @KalpeshRupani but in my case I did not use leading "/"

Comment: Shall I need to pass `Authorization` details in header